# How to fix the async issue of firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to query and update data to firebase. But I cannot get the data. It seems the program doesn't run into ref.observeSingleEvent
what should I do to fix this?

```
    func getId(path:String, value:String?, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: path).queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: value)

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            print("running in getId")
            completion(snapshot.key)                

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
@objc func onTapConfirmed(){

     self.getId(path: "patients", value: self.kardex?.patient?.name) { snapshotKey in
      BookingViewController.kardexDict["patient"] = snapshotKey as AnyObject?

      print("1:get patient name")
      }

     self.getId(path: "nurses", value: BookingTreatmentListController.nurseName) { snapshotKey in
      BookingViewController.kardexDict["nurse"] = snapshotKey as AnyObject?
      print("2:get nurse name")
      }
      Database.database().reference().child("kardexes").child(BookingViewController.newKardex.id).updateChildValues(BookingViewController.kardexDict)

     print("save kardexDict")

 }
```

I expect to get the following result

"1:get patient name" -> "running in getId" -> 
"2:get nurse name" -> "running in getId" -> "save kardexDict"

But I got
"1:get patient name" -> "2:get nurse name" -> "save kardexDict"

and the data in kardexDict is not correct since the data is not obtained from function getId() 
What can I do to force the program follow my order I expected.

Comment: It's much better practice to *force yourself to follow the order of the program* 

Comment: @vadian thanks for the reply, yes, i can follow the order of the program. But i dont know how to wait for observeSingleEvent to be finished. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function. The API is different but the behavior is exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using firebase in the wrong way:

- `observeSingleEvent` runs asynchronously, so the order of events will be:  "running in getId" -> "1:get patient name"
- `updateChildValues` will typically called before any of the `observeSingleEvent` finishes

Hence, you first write the empty(?) `kardexDict` to firebase, before you even get the patient or nurse name.

Also, be aware the the `completion` closure does not run in the main thread. Therefore, you will likely observe some unpredictable concurrency issues / race conditions.
What you have to do is, to wait for all `observeSingleEvent` to be finished, and then write the data back.

---

### Update

So, an more or less 1-to-1 transfer of your idea *could* look like this (might not exactly compile, because I don't have your environment running):

```
func getId(path:String, value:String?, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: path).queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: value)

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        print("running in getId")
        completion(snapshot.key)                

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

@objc func onTapConfirmed(){

    let patientName = self.kardex?.patient?.name
    let nurseName = BookingTreatmentListController.nurseName
    self.getId(path: "patients", value: patientName) { snapshotKey in
        print("1:got patient")
        let patient = snapshotKey as AnyObject?
        self.getId(path: "nurses", value: nurseName) { snapshotKey in
            print("2:got nurse")
            let nurse = snapshotKey as AnyObject?
            DispatchQueue.Main.async {
                print("save kardexDict (in main thread!")
                BookingViewController.kardexDict["patient"] = patient
                BookingViewController.kardexDict["nurses"] = nurse
                let kardexes = Database.database().reference().child("kardexes")
                kardexes.child(BookingViewController.newKardex.id).updateChildValues(BookingViewController.kardexDict)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, it might not be *that* efficient, because there are two separate web calls involved (first the patients, then the nurses). Maybe you better use `observe` instead of `observeSingleEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can I wait. After print("save kardexDict"), the function onTapConfirmed()  is finished. So I dont know how to wait for all observeSingleEvent to be finished.